# How to uninstall "cowsay" package (Linux Mint 17 KDE)

Tags: linux-mint, packages

I don't like the "cowsay" package which is installed by default in Linux Mint (KDE).

I tried to uninstalled it, but it also uninstalled the following packages

```
mint-artwork-common 
mint-artwork-kde 
mint-configuration-kde
mintsystem 
ubuntu-system-adjustments
```

It is very disappointing. Do you have any idea how to remove just the "cowsay" package? Thank you.

Comment: It seems these configuration utilities contain hooks to control `cowsay`, perhaps for use as an MOTD.

Comment: @DragonLord: What is MOTD?

Comment: Message of the day. It's a message displayed to the user at login time. Some systems are configured to run a program like `fortune` for this purpose. It may just be that the configuration utilities provide `cowsay` as an option for the MOTD. Making `cowsay` a requirement for these packages isn't great design, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `equivs` to generate a dummy `cowsay` package with higher version.
2. Install the new dummy pacakge.